# Varying number of conditions

Tags: python, control-flow, multiple-conditions

I'm working on matching input data from a form style GUI with information contained in files.

I want the use to be able to fill out one/any/all number of boxes to be matched in the files

What I think I'm looking for is something like

```
if ((filled_boxes[0] == file[0]) and (filled_boxes[1] == file[1]) and ....
```

but allow for a ranging number of conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), combined with [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to test for *all* conditions:

```
if all(box ==  f for box, f in zip(filled_boxes, file)):
```

Here `zip()` pairs up files and boxes, loops over each pair, and `all()` returns `True` only if *all* the pairs match.

Quick demos of what `zip()` and `all()` do:

```
>>> zip([1, 2, 3], ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'])
[(1, 'spam'), (2, 'ham'), (3, 'eggs')]
>>> all(i < 5 for i in range(5))
True
>>> all(i < 5 for i in range(10))
False
```

where `all()` only needs to test enough of the generator expression to determine that there is one `False` value for it to return `False` as well.

Comment: I have to figure out how to implement it the way I need but I think I love you